# PowerShell bind arrow keys to command history search

Tags: powershell, search, key-bindings, command-history

In bash, I can bind the Up and Down arrow keys to history search with

```
"\e[5~": history-search-backward
"\e[6~": history-search-forward
```

in `~/.inputrc`.
If at the prompt I type `ca` and then the Up key, it will bring the next command line in history that matches `ca` as the beginning.

Using Ctrl + R for `(reverse-i-search)` is useful, and PS has this.
But I find the bindings above quite more efficient to work.

**Can this be achieved with PowerShell?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add the following lines to your Powershell profile.

Mine is at `%HOME%\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1`.

```
# Reverse Search
Set-PSReadLineOption -HistorySearchCursorMovesToEnd
Set-PSReadlineKeyHandler -Key UpArrow -Function HistorySearchBackward
Set-PSReadlineKeyHandler -Key DownArrow -Function HistorySearchForward
```

These are sourced from the powershell [PSReadLine](https://github.com/PowerShell/PSReadLine/blob/577d1444a073a5daa4666bc627af041aa631d093/PSReadLine/SamplePSReadlineProfile.ps1#L19) repo.

Funnily enough, we came to ask the same question 12 hours apart :)

EDIT months later as I still come back to this:

This provides bash-like autocomplete

```
Set-PSReadlineKeyHandler -Key Tab -Function Complete
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks!